# Python code working on one computer, but not other: "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list"

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm running this code to get a list of tables from Google Big Query, using subprocess and the bq command from GSUtils. For some reason that I don't understand, in one computer it works (Python 3.8.6), but in the other (Python 3.8.7) I get the error posted below.

What is wrong with the code?

Thanks!

```
import subprocess
import re


params=[]
params.append("--use_legacy_sql=false ")
params.append(r"SELECT table_name FROM Exportar_CSV.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema IN ('Exportar_CSV')")
process = subprocess.run(['bq','query',params], shell=True, capture_output=True)
output = process.stdout.decode("utf-8")
#Convert the output to a list type.
table_list=output.split("\r\n")
table_list=[item.strip("|").strip() for item in table_list]
table_list= [ item for item in table_list if "table_name" not in item and "+--------" not in item and '' != item]
```

This is the error that python throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Export_to_CSV.py", line 8, in <module>
    process = subprocess.run(['bq','query',params], shell=True, capture_output=True)
  File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 1247, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 549, in list2cmdline
    for arg in map(os.fsdecode, seq):
  File "C:\Python\lib\os.py", line 818, in fsdecode
    filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`.
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Comment: I've upgraded both computers to python 3.8.7 and in the one where it was working.. is still working.

Comment: Is there a reason you are inserting `params` into the list in you call to `subprocess.run`?  That way you end up with a list inside a list.  Does it help if you concatenate the arguments (i.e. write `['bq', 'query'] + params`) instead?

Comment: this code should give error on both computers - only idea: you run different code on other computer.

Comment: totally sure it was the same code.. I've created a new file on both, and copy/paste the code..

Answer (score 0):

As Luke Woodward says, it seems to be that the argument is a list inside a list. So changing that, it worked on both.
Still don't know why it worked in one computer...

```
params=[]
params.append(str("bq"))
params.append(str("query"))
params.append(str("--use_legacy_sql=false"))
params.append(str(r"SELECT table_name FROM Exportar_CSV.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema IN ('Exportar_CSV')"))
process = subprocess.run(params, shell=True, capture_output=True)
output = process.stdout.decode("utf-8")
#Convert the output to a list type.
table_list=output.split("\r\n")
table_list=[item.strip("|").strip() for item in table_list]
table_list= [ item for item in table_list if "table_name" not in item and "+--------" not in item and '' != item]
```